# Exportar um dicionário para arquivo .txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá.

Eu gostaria de saber como eu faço pra exportar um dicinário para um arquivo .txt.

e como importar os dados que estão no arquivo.txt para o dicionário, no programa. Quando eu importo, o dicionário fica todo bugado, como eu importo corretamente?

Answer (score 5):

Se você está trabalhando somente com os tipos de dados padrão da linguagem, isto é, "int", "float", "str" e "bool" você pode exportar e importar o dicionário como um arquivo JSON:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import json

dicionario = {
    'nome': 'Fulano de Tal',
    'idade': 30,
    'saldo': 520.37,
    'online': True,
}

open('dicionario.json','w').write(json.dumps(dicionario))

with open('dicionario.json', 'r') as file_json:
    dicionario_2 = json.loads(file_json.read())

print(dicionario_2)
```

Porém, se você tem outros tipos de dados você pode usar o [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pickle.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
from datetime import datetime

dicionario = {
    'nome': 'Fulano de Tal',
    'online': False,
    'ultimo_login': datetime.now()
}

open('dicionario.pickle','w').write(pickle.dumps(dicionario))

with open('dicionario.pickle', 'r') as file_pickle:
    dicionario_2 = pickle.loads(file_pickle.read())

print(dicionario_2)
```

Comment: Tu também podes usar sem o read(), json.load(file_json), também quando escreves no ficheiro. https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#saving-structured-data-with-json, https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load